# ash: you need to specify whom to kill

Tags: bash, kill, cat, ash

I'm trying to give a mqtt call the output of `cat` as value; however it is important that the `cat` call gets killed immediatly after putting something in the variable, since the targeted file has to emtpy itself and only does so, when not being read. But currently the call doesn't get killed. When I kill it manually by killing it's PID, it runs the rest of the code smoothly but prints out "`ash: you need to specify whom to kill` .

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/ash
while true;do
rs=$( cat /dev/rs232 & )
pid=$!
kill ${pid}
mosquitto_pub -h IP -m "$rs" -t rs_test/message
done
```

Using `kill $( pgrep cat )` insteda of `pid=$!` and `kill ${pid}` seems to also not work

Comment: `cat` is executed in a subshell, so `$!` isn't defined when you try to assign its value to `pid`. Further, `rs` is always going to be the empty string because the command subsitution completes as soon as `cat` is backgrounded, before `cat` can actually write any output. Finally, you can't store arbitrary binary data in a shell string, because any null byte output by `cat` would be treated as terminating the string, not a character to store in the string.

Comment: In any case, killing `cat` immediately would leave `rs` in an undefined state, because there's no way of knowing how much data `cat` managed to read and subsequently write before being killed.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I just want to mention that while @chepner point out `cat` is run in a subshell, you may consider using `{}` to make it run in the same shell. although you can't assign it as variable (it would be treated as substitution)